# Filter report values in a calculated text box, based on its conditional formatting colors using VBA or Macro builder

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have ms access 2010 and designed a report can calculate text boxes; one text box [Review] is calculating the review within the workdays only, to give the exact review elapsed time during work hours. And the above average [Review] values would be highlighted automatically as following:

- Fore color RGB(255,0,0) "Red"
- Back color RGB(255,255,0) "Yellow"

I would ask your help to Filter this report entries based on the conditional formatting above colors of [Review] text box using VBA code or Macro builder.

I have already tried to design a macro to apply filter, using similar values:

Where condition:

> ([Document Type]="General Letter" And ([Review End Time]-[Review Start Time]/[Qty]-1)>1 And [Hours]>72) Or ([Document Type]="Booklet" And ([Review End Time]-[Review Start Time]/[Qty]-1)>1 And [Hours]>168)

This On Open code is to use a date range of the entries:

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
   DoCmd.OpenForm "DateRange", , , , , acDialog, "CorrespondenceReviewDetails"
   If Not IsLoaded("DateRange") Then
      Cancel = True
   End If
End Sub
```

I got the entries filtered already, but not very identical to the query data. And I need to filter the report entries from the report view, by adding a button to apply filter directly from the report itself.

Conditional Formatting expressions:

> [doctype]="General Letter" And [rnavgintervalqty]>1 OR
>   [doctype]="Booklet" And [rnavgintervalqty]>5 OR
>   [doctype]="Announcement" And [rnavgintervalqty]>5 OR
>   [doctype]="Appeal" And [rnavgintervalqty]>1

Query SQL code:

```
SELECT Correspondence.*, [Review End Time]-[Review Start Time] AS [interval], Int(CSng(Nz([interval],0)*24)) AS Hours, Abs([Due Date]<Now() And Not [Resolved]) AS Overdue, Round(([interval][Qty]),1) AS avginterval, Round(([Hours][Qty]),1) AS avghours, Round(([Minutes][Qty]),1) AS avgminutes, Workdays([Review Start Time],[Review End Time]) AS nrevachvmnt, Round([nrevachvmnt]/[Qty],2)-1 AS navgintervalqty WHERE (((Correspondence.[Document Dated])>=[Forms]![DateRange]![SrchDateFrom] And (Correspondence.[Document Dated])<=[Forms]![DateRange]![SrchDateTo]))
```

Comment: Similar is not same. What are the Conditional Formatting expressions? Edit question.

Comment: Conditional Formatting expressions:[doctype]="General Letter" And [rnavgintervalqty]>1 OR [doctype]="Booklet" And [rnavgintervalqty]>5 OR [doctype]="Announcement" And [rnavgintervalqty]>5 OR [doctype]="Appeal" And [rnavgintervalqty]>1

Comment: Query SQL code: SELECT Correspondence.*, [Review End Time]-[Review Start Time] AS [interval], Int(CSng(Nz([interval],0)*24)) AS Hours, Abs([Due Date]<Now() And Not [Resolved]) AS Overdue, Round(([interval]\[Qty]),1) AS avginterval, Round(([Hours]\[Qty]),1) AS avghours, Round(([Minutes]\[Qty]),1) AS avgminutes, Workdays([Review Start Time],[Review End Time]) AS nrevachvmnt, Round([nrevachvmnt]/[Qty],2)-1 AS navgintervalqty
WHERE (((Correspondence.[Document Dated])>=[Forms]![DateRange]![SrchDateFrom] And (Correspondence.[Document Dated])<=[Forms]![DateRange]![SrchDateTo]))

Comment: Okay, so that was the Conditional Formatting expression. I don't see the same criteria in the Conditional Formatting expression and query WHERE clause. You want to filter report by additional criteria? Is that SQL a saved query object? Now what is the report RecordSource? `Review` is name of textbox on report? Is it bound to `navgintervalqty`? You want a button on report to apply filter? How should users input parameters? Exactly what do you not understand about building filter criteria with VBA? What have you attempted?

Comment: [rnavgintervalqty] in report conditional formatting and [Review] text boxes on the report bound to [navgintervalqty] in the SQL saved query object. Also record source is a query builder name Correspondence Extended KPI. I actually want a button on report to apply filter, users enter data range parameters from a separate form ![DateRange], using ![SrchDateFrom] & ![SrchDateTo] fields. I can build my filter using both VBA and Macro, what I need exactly is how to refer to the dynamic font color RGB (255,0,0) or back color RGB(255,255,0) of [rnavgintervalqty] or [Review] text boxes on my report?

Comment: Not seeing any way to do that. It is possible to read the settings of Conditional Formatting rules, but not determine what color has been applied per record. And if you could, don't really see how that would help filter records.

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts and trials, I would create a Macro for the time-being that would filter the data. However, I'd keep searching for a solution because the filtered entries of the report NOT very identical to the query data. If I am able to reach for any acceptable solution, then I would share it with the community. Regards,